# Implode array of dates and change date format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following code of which I want to retrieve dates from db. The code outputs the disered list, but in different date format.

```
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$dates = implode("\n",$array);
return $dates;
```

Result is:

```
2021-05-26
2021-05-27
2021-05-28
2021-05-29
2021-05-30
```

I need this format: m/d/Y

I tried this:

```
`$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

$dates = implode("\n",$array);
$newDate = date("m/d/y", strtotime($dates));
return $newDate;`

But the result is just one result and wrong:

01/01/70

Format changed but i lost the correct dates

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with? Map the array with a [date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php) function.

Comment: I uploaded more information, sorry my first ask on stackoverflow. I m learning and i m not expert.  My problem is combine the strtotime fuction with implode. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the mysql function `DATE_FORMAT` in your SELECT and you don't need to reformat it.

> ```
> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2021-05-26','%m/%d/%Y')
> ```
>
> ```
> | DATE_FORMAT('2021-05-26','%m/%d/%Y') |
> | :----------------------------------- |
> | 05/26/2021                           |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e114c67afae809392a23882706de554)*

In your query you use it like advertised and replacwe the date with the column

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%m/%d/%Y') FROM reservations WHERE object_id IN (select id from rooms WHERE sub_id='$value')
```

your code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection** so use **prepared statements with parameters** see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thank a lot for answers. My query is exactly this:
"SELECT date FROM reservations WHERE object_id IN (select id from rooms WHERE sub_id='$value')"
How i can use that fuction you saied?

Comment: i added the query, but your code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection** so use **prepared statements with parameters** see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Thank you very much for help. This works perfect. I can use a fix value in real project so i will no have sql injection. In anycase thank you very much for the link, i need to study this too...

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_map to apply a callback to all elements of an array. With the strtotime and date function, you can change the format of your dates. [Documentation on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php)

```
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$dates = array_map(function($element) {
    return date("Ymd", $element);
}, $dates);
$dates = implode("\n",$array);
return $dates;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried different formats but the result is always the same : 2021-05-26...

Comment: To get different formats to work I just did the same but did `return date("Ymd", strtotime($element));`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, is to turn them into DateTime objects, then use format to get the result you are after. So something like:

```
$date = "2021-05-26";

$DT = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date);
echo $DT -> format("m/d/Y");
```

This method also gives you an ability to do other conversions and/or modify the time etc.

[DateTime create from format docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

[DateTime format docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)